# Using Redis with libuv in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, redis, libuv, hiredis

I'm trying to compile the example program that comes with hiredis (C++), using libuv as an event library. The Windows-compatible version of Redis uses a library called Win32_Interop.

I've run into two problems:

1. Both libuv and Win32_Interop define ssize_t, but as conflicting types.
2. Both libuv and Win32_interop use WinSocks. Linking the program against ws2_32.lib causes duplicate definitions, and not doing so causes unresolved external symbols.

How can I resolve these issues?